# specifying missing values to pdist in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

how can missing values be specified when calling `pdist` in scipy? i.e. the function described here:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html

for example if you have:

```
pdist(X, "euclidean")
```

but `X` might contain missing values like the string `"NA"` and you want those to be excluded in pairwise comparisons among `X`'s columns. the behavior i'm looking for is to not consider missing values when getting the euclidean distance between any pair of columns in `X`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to fill your X array with np.nan for the points to be excluded. For example, assuming a 2D case with a X a (10,2) array:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.random.rand(10, 2)
```

Let's assume you want to exclude X[7] from the calculation:

```
X[7] = np.nan
my_dist = pdist(X, "euclidean")
```

Then, you'll see that my_dist has 'nan' for the pairs that involved calculating distance with the excluded element. You can exclude multiple elements.

A better idea would be to use a numpy masked array, but pdist ignores masked arrays and uses the data anyway. However, once you have the output my_dist, you can convert it to a masked array so that the nans don't get in the way of future array operations:

```
my_dist = np.ma.array(my_dist, mask = ~np.isfinite(my_dist))
```